# On a server running both PHP and MySQL, is it more efficient to make multiple SQL calls with one PHP loop, or vice versa?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Windows Server 2012 with IIS running MySQL 5.7 and PHP 5.6. I have to build some complex JSON using multiple data sets and loops.

Would it be more efficient for me to do one SQL call and then build my JSON using a number of PHP loops on an array of data?

SQL:

```
SELECT stuff, item_id
FROM here
WHERE item = 1 
OR item = 2 
OR item = 3 
OR item = 4
```

PHP:

```
foreach($sql_results as $item)
{
  // build JSON by looking at $item['item_id']
}
```

Or would it be better for me to do each SQL call individually (in a loop of some kind) and build the JSON as the calls are being made?

SQL:

```
SELECT stuff, item_id
FROM here
WHERE item = 1 

SELECT stuff, item_id
FROM here
WHERE item = 2 

SELECT stuff, item_id
FROM here
WHERE item = 3 

SELECT stuff, item_id
FROM here
WHERE item = 4
```

PHP:

```
$item
// build JSON directly from each call
```

With a very large amount of calls, either PHP or MySQL could get bogged down... so which one would I go with as my workhorse here?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb it's nearly always a good idea to have as few queries to the database as possible. I would never put a query inside a loop if I could help it.

Comment: You marked the answer as accepted, but there's zero reasoning behind that answer and there's very little info from your side. You didn't even determine what the bottleneck is, yet you're trying to optimize the unknown factor. That's not pragmatic, is it? Until you determine what the bottleneck MIGHT be, you can't fight to prevent it. As it stands, you have no idea if you are CPU or I/O bound. Until you determine that - your optimization will be a complete and utter waste of your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The db request is definitely more time consuming, so I would choose the first approach with one SQL query and PHP loop.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, one query will be better solution.

Also, as a side note, you can use `item IN(...)` instead of using `OR` condition multiple times